# ORA-01843, invalid month in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core

I have build some Apis and now I have published them from the server (Windows Server 2019).

My issue is from my localhost this code work fine:

```
string sql = "select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5  from Table where column1 = 'BOOK' and column2 = 'GNF' and column3 = 'EUR' and column5 >= TO_DATE('23-dec-21', 'DD-MON-RR') and ROWNUM <= 1";

_logger.LogDebug(sql);

command.CommandText = sql;

OracleDataReader reader =  command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    rate_Model.field1 = reader["column1"].ToString();
    rate_Model.field2 = reader["column2"].ToString();
    rate_Model.field3 = reader["column3"].ToString();
    rate_Model.field4 = reader["column4"].ToString();
};
```

But on the server (Windows Server 2019) I am always getting this error:

> ORA-01843, invalid month

I don't know what is wrong from the server, I have checked the format from the server and it is 'dd-mon-yy'. Also if I remove the function `To_date` for converting the string to date, I'm getting this error

> ORA-01858,a non-numeric character was located where a number was expected

I really don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Might be orthogonal, shouldn't it be `RRRR`, not `RR`? And yes, I see that you're specifying the year as two-digit, but RRRR should handle that.

Comment: Which version of oracle is this?

Comment: Hello @LasseV.Karlsen, the format of the date from the oracle DB is 'DD-MON-RR' exemple '23-dec-21', also if i put '23-dec-2021' from the query its works from localhost, but from the server  i have 'invalid month'

Comment: Have you tried just doing `SELECT TO_DATE('23-dec-21','DD-MON-RR') FROM dual`? Does that work? Is the type of `column5` a date or text?

Comment: Hello @LasseV.Karlsen im using this version:  <PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="3.21.4" />

Comment: Dates in Oracle have no format, they're binary values. Formats apply only when parsing strings into dates or formatting a date into a string for display. By the way, `23-dec-21` reintroduces the Y2K bug. Why would that mean 2021 instead of 1921? 2 years ago the big IT news was that Barclays and LLoyd's internet banking sites crashed when they started translating `20` to 1920.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for your sample data; and the NLS settings for both the C# and "localhost" sessions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Using the `RR` format model (which the OP explicitly uses in the `TO_DATE` function call) means it will be parsed as 2021 and not 1921.

Comment: If you want to pass a date value to a query, use a parameterized query instead and pass a `DateTime` value from C# instead of parsing strings. To get rid of the OracleCommand boilerplate you can use [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper). The entire query can become `var results=connection.Query<Rate_Model>("select ... where column5=:date...",new {date=new DateTime(2021,12,23)})'`

Comment: @MT0 and what exactly is the "new" cutoff date? That's exactly what happened at Lloyd's and RBS - someone assumed the cutoff would never come. Then it came. There's no reason to reintroduce bugs. And if you assume the new cutoff is far away - what about pension dates and funds? Those can have dates "far" in the past or future

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [The documentation is here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F). There is no issue using `RR` (assuming that you are using it as it was meant to be used) and there is no "cutoff" when it will stop working as intended.

Comment: HI @LasseV.Karlsen  column5 is a date, yeah this query works from sql developper even from the server:  SELECT TO_DATE('23-dec-21','DD-MON-RR') FROM dual ;

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use a date literal: `select colum1,colum2,colum3,colum4,colum5  from Table where colum1='BOOK' and colum2='GNF' and colum3='EUR' and colum5 >= DATE '2021-12-23' and ROWNUM <=1`?

Comment: @MT0 on the contrary, the link you provided puts the cutoff at 2050. Why not use an unambiguous date literal instead? Why not provide the date from the client side?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the "That is" in the "The RR Datetime Format Element" section gives the exact behaviour and there is no "cutoff". If in 2050 it is run then `00` will be parsed as 2100 then if its run in 2150 then `00` would be parsed as 2200 there is no "cutoff" and it will keep working as intended (and if you want to use 4-digit years then `RR` will work with it, unless you also specify the `fx` format model).

Comment: Hello @MT0  this query is not working from sql developper: --> select colum1,colum2,colum3,colum4,colum5  from Table where colum1='BOOK' and colum2='GNF' and colum3='EUR' and colum5 >= DATE '2021-12-23' and ROWNUM <=1

Comment: @Sylla Are you sure you are not storing `colum5` as a string? If you are then [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=66772acb08bc07a3d0ea94e479928589) would apply if you had different NLS settings and were using implicit string-to-date conversions. If you are storing it as a `DATE` then your code ought to work as execution will not involve implicit conversions so would be independent of the NLS settings.

Comment: RR may keep working "as intended", but "as intended" is a sliding window.  The entire RR and RRRR was meant as a temporary band-aid to buy some time in correctly remediating y2k.  People forget that in 1998, most programs stored 'dates' as either numbers or character strings, and with only 2-digit years.  Full, correct remediation of actually changing the storage to a 4-digit year could be frightfully difficult, due to the amount of code that would need to be changed.  The only _correct_ way to deal with dates now is to explicitly specify 4-digit years - YYYY format.

Comment: Hello @PanagiotisKanavos, after reading the documentation and following the doc i have finally used the -->Dapper and its very easy and powerful, I'm very happy and my issue is resolved thanks you so much i appreciate  and thanks all others

Answer (score 1):

I finally used Mr. @**PanagiotisKanavos** advice, that is to use -->Dapper, its very easy and powerful, I'm very happy and my issue is resolved thanks you so much i appreciate and thanks all others.
All this code

```
    string sql = "select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5  from Table where column1 = 'BOOK' and column2 = 'GNF' and column3 = 'EUR' and column5 >= TO_DATE('23-dec-21', 'DD-MON-RR') and ROWNUM <= 1";

_logger.LogDebug(sql);

command.CommandText = sql;

OracleDataReader reader =  command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    rate_Model.field1 = reader["column1"].ToString();
    rate_Model.field2 = reader["column2"].ToString();
    rate_Model.field3 = reader["column3"].ToString();
    rate_Model.field4 = reader["column4"].ToString();
};
```

is replaced to this line of code:

```
var results=connection.Query<Rate_Model>("select colums where column5=:date...",new {date=new DateTime(2021,12,23)})';
```

Thanks you so much.